# Use of deleted function Error as soon as class inherits from QObject

Tags: c++, qt

I am having trouble with a class inheriting from QObject. My problem is that I want my class queueTcp to inherit from QQueue so I can add objects of another class commandTcp to it. Everything works fine until I let commandTcp inherit QObject.

When I try to compile, I get 11 errors like:

> use of deleted function 'QObject::QObject(const QObject&)
>
> QObject::QObject(const QObject&)' is private

I tried to figure them out for the last days, but couldn´t find any solution that works for me.

My code is:

queueTcp.h

```
#ifndef QUEUETCP_H
#define QUEUETCP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <commandtcp.h>
#include <QQueue>

class queueTcp: public QObject, public QQueue<commandTcp>
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    queueTcp();
    void newCommand();
};

#endif // QUEUETCP_H
```

commandTcp.h

```
#ifndef COMMANDTCP_H
#define COMMANDTCP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QByteArray>

class commandTcp: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT

private:
    QByteArray storeCommand;
    int arraySize;
    int destinationAddress;
    int length;
    int command;

public:
    commandTcp(int, int, int, QByteArray, int);
};

#endif // COMMANDTCP_H
```

queueTcp.cpp

```
#include "queuetcp.h"

queueTcp::queueTcp() {

}


void queueTcp::newCommand() {
    commandTcp temp(63, 8, 208, 0, 1);
    this->enqueue(temp);
}
```

commandTcp.cpp

```
#include "commandtcp.h"


commandTcp::commandTcp(int _destinationAddress, int _length, int _command, QByteArray _userData, int _arraySize)
{
    arraySize = _arraySize;
    storeCommand = {0};
    storeCommand.append(_userData);
    destinationAddress = _destinationAddress;
    length = _length;
    command = _command;
}
```

Where is my problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the `enqueue` function uses a pass by value for the parameter, this code will not compile since `QObject` has a deleted copy constructor. However, the `enqueue` function is not shown in this code. Please edit with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the problem is that you are trying to copy something that cannot be copied. The solution is to not copy it ;). Pass by reference as suggested by Arnav

Comment: @ArnavBorborah 'enqueue' is derived from QQueue class.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Like rafix07 said 'enqueue' is derived from QQueue. The code should be MCVE. How would I not copy it?

Comment: @rafix07 Ah, my mistake; Thanks for pointing that out. According to [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqueue.html#enqueue), it does seem that `enqueue` uses pass by reference. However, the problem is still that you are copying something that cannot be copied.

Comment: @tobi303
Indeed, to my knowledge QObjects are typically meant to be referenced by a pointer. The copy constructor and assignment operator are explicitly deleted.
Julian, I believe QQueue does not require its items to be derived from QObject. Is there a reason you want commandTcp to derive from it?

Comment: @TimSmit I need commandTcp to derive from it, so I can use signals & slots

Comment: Use [composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: Thanks, everyone.
Now it works. Like you all said I just had to enqueue pointers to queueTcp instead of copying objects of commandTcp.